# Spring Security java configuration confusion

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, configuration

Why the login isn't prompted with following configuration? When I try to access */public/user*, I get error 403 (access denied). However, if I uncomment those commented lines at `WebServiceSecurityConfiguration.configure`, I got redirected to login page, as desired. Why those lines are needed for from-login being properly configured, as the antMatcher matches different path in the first place. I guess there is some conflict, which misconfigures the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, but I don't really have idea how that happens. What I'm trying to achieve is configuring two security chains, one for login path to obtain the JWT token, and another for web services to authenticate against the token. Everything works perfectly with those lines uncommented, but I noticed by accident form-login stopped working without them, and am super confused why is that.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("javasecurity")
@Order(11)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenHandler tokenHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")).and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").authorities(
                    new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"),
                    new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")).and()
            .withUser("guest").password("guest").authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_GUEST"));
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .logout();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                tokenHandler.setToken(response, authentication.getName());
                response.getWriter().println("User authenticated and cookie sent");
                response.flushBuffer();
            }
        };
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("javasecurity")
    @Order(10)
    public static class WebServiceSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TestAuthenticationFilter testAuthenticationFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secured/**")
                    .authenticated();
//              .and()
//              .antMatcher("/secured/**")
//                  .securityContext().securityContextRepository(new NullSecurityContextRepository())
//                  .and()
//                  .addFilterAt(testAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }
```

--

```
@Component("TestAuthenticationFilter")
public class TestAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired
    private TokenHandler tokenHandler;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("TestAuthenticationFilter doFitler");
        attemptAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        clearAuthentication();
        System.out.println("doFitler end");
    }

    public void attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            UserDetails user = tokenHandler.loadUserFromToken(request);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }

    public void clearAuthentication() {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class DisableFilterRegistration {

        @Autowired
        private TestAuthenticationFilter filter;

        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean disablerBean() {
            FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
            bean.setEnabled(false);
            return bean;
        }
    }

}
```

--

```
@Component("TokenHandler")
public class TokenHandler {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public void setToken(HttpServletResponse response, String username) {
        response.addCookie(new Cookie("user", username));
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserFromToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws BadCredentialsException {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        Cookie token = null;
        for (Cookie c : cookies) {
            if (c.getName().equals("user")) {
                token = c;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (token == null)
            return null;

        else 
            return userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(token.getValue());
    }
}
```

--

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public")
public class PublicController {

    @GetMapping("/norole")
    public String noRole() {
        return "no role";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String roleUser() {
        return "role_user";
    }
}
```

--

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/secured")
public class SecuredController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String roleUser() {
        return "role_user";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String roleAdmin() {
        return "role_admin";
    }

    @GetMapping("/norole")
    public String noRole() {
        return "no role";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Login-from got functional again after declaring adding

```
http.antMatcher("/secured/**")
```

As the first call in the `WebServiceSecurityConfiguration.configure`. Does that mean that without it the configuration negates the form-login, which is configured *after* this particular configuration? Also, it seems like the position of `antMatcher` can be arbitrary, is this the case? Could someone explain what is actually happening there?